# Prestashop wrong invoice order

Tags: prestashop, invoice

I have a problem, a customer places an order and the invoice doesn't match what he bought and paid for.

he buys 3 articles the invoice displays 12....

where should I look for to solve this BIG problem? I am on Prestashop 1.6.9

I didn't delete orders manually throught database, this is my first order...

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Are these products combinations and if so do they contain one attribute or more than one? Do you have any modules that are overriding the OrderInvoice class? Check in override--classes--order.

I would probably start in classes--order--OrderInvoice.php. The Invoices are created using this class and I believe they use the method getProducts to loop through the products from the order.